# Couchbase + Spring Data: Get only field instead of whole entity using @Query

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, sql++

I'm still relatively new in Couchbase with N1QL and Spring Data. I try to retrieve a list of all distinct fields. I don't want to retrieve the whole entity since I expect the result to be rather large.

My documents look like

```
{
  "fieldname": "something",
  ...
}
```

My repository class is

```
@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface MyRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    @Query("select distinct fieldname from mybucket")
    Object findAllDistinctFields();

}
```

But I always get an Exception '*Query returning a primitive type are expected to return exactly 1 result*'

```
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseQueryExecutionException: Query returning a primitive type are expected to return exactly 1 result, got 100014
  at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeSingleProjection(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:193)
  at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeDependingOnType(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:134)
  at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.execute(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:93)
```

Is there a way to return only all the fields and not whole entities? If I try the query 'select distinct sku from backinstock;' in Couchbase's GUI it works fine!

BTW I'm working with spring-data-couchbase 2.1.5 and Couchbase 4.5.1-2844.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is projections support which can fetch specific fields of an entity in Spring data Ingalls 2.2.0-RC1 release. The reference documentation is here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#_dto_projections